# I want to use one table primary key in another model automatically in yii

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

```
CREATE TABLE `authordetails` (
  `a1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `a2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a4` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a5` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `docid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`),
  KEY `FK_authordetails` (`docid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_authordetails` FOREIGN KEY (`docid`) REFERENCES `details` (`details_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `details` (
  `articletype` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `titleofpaper` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `abstract` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`details_id`),
  KEY `FK_details` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_details` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `signup` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to use detais-id in authordetails table as doc_id when i open author detais table it will autometically show details_id
please help me

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have AuthorDetails model for authordetails table and Details model for details table, then you need to follow the steps below:

Add following relationship in AuthorDetails class relation method:

```
'details' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Details', 'doc_id'),
```

Add following relationship in Details class:

```
'author_details' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'AuthorDetails', 'doc_id'),
```

Now you can access:

```
$details->author_details;
```

Comment: Thanks mshakell but i cant get third line how can i access details_id in authordetails model as docid

Comment: like $this->docid=$details_details_id;

Comment: @user3323189 Can you please add part of your model code so we can further understand what you require.

Comment: sir,actually when i redirect on author details model from details model in docid field it will be fetch autometically details_id and add in the table user cannotenter docid

Comment: i dont want that user will enter docid it will be eaul to details id which will be in another model called details model hope u can understand

Comment: Can you please add your view, controller and model code here in your question? I think you will require to add a dropdown on your view which will help you in assigning correct values.